# How do you make it so that at the end of a process, the ongoing notification vibrates and plays sound?

Tags: android, audio, android-notifications, android-notification-bar, android-vibration

I have an application that starts an ongoing notification and then completes a process. At the end of the process, the notification is terminated, but before that happens I want the Notification to make the system vibrate and play sound. I am not totally sure how to make it play sound a vibrate on command and would really like some help on this. I have already set up the notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; and the notification.vibrate = pattern; Thank you in advance and if I wasn't clear enough, let me know.

Comment: What such property is not working for or something else?

Comment: Well, I want the device to play sound and vibrate when I destroy the Notification, or right before I destroy it. I am using notification.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID); to destroy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to look [Notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html)
and [Notification Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) 
for playing a sound in notification.

Comment: That was the first place I looked and there was no answer to my question.